# How to use Bootstrap 3 Grid

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having troubles with getting the grid to work, i have followed multiple tutorials and forums, but nothing will work. I'm using Sublime Text for my editor, and copying all the CDN tags and wrapping everything in a div="container"

Whenever i preview it, the text appears on the far left, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Try it out in CodePen or JSFiddle and if it still does not work, post a link. Also check browser developer tools console for any errors. In chrome its "inspect element".

Comment: Also, try checking it against [Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint#in-the-browser)

Comment: Still cannot get it to respond how i want it, i have saved a 'codepen' for anyone to go over, to see if i have made a mistake somewhere.. 

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoGWgJ

@MartinMalinda

Comment: The structure looks good! Only thing in the codepen would be that you refer to a local bootstrap css/js file. I've made a fork that refers to one from a cdn, see http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/zxrwON?editors=110. If you make the screen larger, you'll notice that the Hello World has some margin from the left of the screen.

Comment: Bootstrap is not being included properly. Once it is everything should work fine: http://www.bootply.com/nVFeYrMdgz

Answer (score 0):

here is the [pen](http://codepen.io/vinrav/pen/Ggomme)

added some classes and css.

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-centered">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-centered">
            Hello World!
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-centered ">
          <div class="col-*-*"></div>
          <div class="col-*-*"></div>
          <div class="col-*-*"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-centered">

      </div>
  </div>

 /* centered columns styles */
 .row-centered {
     text-align:center;
 }
 .col-centered {
     display:inline-block;
     float:none;
     /* reset the text-align */
     text-align:left;
     /* inline-block space fix */
     margin-right:-4px;
 }
```

Read [this](http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns) for more details